# Rails Model.find() not returning information (returns hash)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using `Postgresql` and I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but calling my database in my

**helper.rb**:

```
def get_info
    info = Scraper.find(1)
    puts info
end
```

in my **controller.rb** via a post request, like such:

```
def create
    helpers.get_info
end
```

is returning

```
#<Scraper:0x00007f96f9738ce0>
```

As opposed to the actual information from my database:

```
<Scraper id: 1, restaurant: => "subway">
```

Comment: What is the actual information you expected?

Comment: @Tai according to the docs I should be retrieving the object corresponding to the supplied primary key http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html

Comment: `#<Scraper:0x00007f96f9738ce0>` is not a hash, it is a instance of Scraper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`puts` prints class and Object Id for complex object. To print details about object, you can use `inspect`:

```
puts info.inspect
```

For more details, you can checkout here: https://vitobotta.com/2011/01/17/prettier-user-friendly-printing-of-ruby-objects/

Answer (score 3):

Modify following code

```
def get_info
    info = Scraper.find(1)
    puts info
end
```

as

```
def get_info
   Scraper.find(1)
end
```

This will work, no need to use `puts info` or even if you want to use `puts` then you can use

`puts info.inspect`

Answer (score 1):

```
puts info.inspect
```

I suggest you to read the [ruby on rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord)